# Retrieving objects own properties based on key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get the `keys` from an object using coffeescript where the `key` is a certain value, but I'm also getting function properties along with the objects own properties.

In getting the function properties I get this error since the `track by` expression doesn't exist on those function properties.

> [ngRepeat:dupes]Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: `prod in products | track by prod.ProductTypeCode`, Duplicate key: `undefined`

This is by `track by` expression:

```
<option ng-repeat="prod in products | track by prod.ProductTypeCode"
        value="{{prod.ProductTypeCode}}">{{prod.ProductType}}
</option>
```

I specified the `own key` on the `for of` loop, but I still get functions such as `isEmpty`, and `contains` in my result array.

I'm using this `for of` loop.

`product for own key, product of $scope.products when key isnt 'RTMT'`

This is my `$scope.Products` which contains the keys.

```
{
  CK: {
    ProductCategoryCode: 'DEP',
    ProductCategory: 'Deposit',
    ProductTypeCode: 'CK'
  },
  RTMT: {
    ProductCategoryCode: 'RTMT',
    ProductCategory: 'Retirement',
    ProductTypeCode: 'IRA'
  },
  SAV: {
    ProductCategoryCode: 'DEP',
    ProductCategory: 'Deposit',
    ProductTypeCode: 'SAV'
  },
  TD: {
    ProductCategoryCode: 'DEP',
    ProductCategory: 'Deposit',
    ProductTypeCode: 'TD'
  }
}
```

While I do get only `CK`, `SAV`, and `TD` I also get this:

[image: Result from for loop]

How do I just get the `Object` types and not the `function` types in coffeescript?

Using the compiled javascript, it seems to work in this snippet but shows the functions also in Firefox's debug window.

```js
// Generated
var hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
  indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) {
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  };

var obj = {
  CK: {
    ProductCategoryCode: 'DEP',
    ProductCategory: 'Deposit',
    ProductTypeCode: 'CK'
  },
  RTMT: {
    ProductCategoryCode: 'RTMT',
    ProductCategory: 'Retirement',
    ProductTypeCode: 'IRA'
  },
  SAV: {
    ProductCategoryCode: 'DEP',
    ProductCategory: 'Deposit',
    ProductTypeCode: 'SAV'
  },
  TD: {
    ProductCategoryCode: 'DEP',
    ProductCategory: 'Deposit',
    ProductTypeCode: 'TD'
  }
};

console.log(getValues(obj));


function getValues(obj) {
  // Generated
  var key, product, ref, results;
  ref = obj; // $scope.products;
  results = [];
  for (key in ref) {
    if (!hasProp.call(ref, key)) continue;
    product = ref[key];
    if (key !== 'RTMT') {
      results.push(product);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the `typeof` each property to see if it's a function:

```
function getValues(obj) {
  // Generated
  var key, product, ref, results;
  ref = obj; // $scope.products;
  results = [];
  for (key in ref) {
    if (!hasProp.call(ref, key)) continue;
    product = ref[key];
    if (key !== 'RTMT' && typeof ref[key] !== 'function') {
      results.push(product);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: I would have to do this check in the coffeescript since this js is generated from that.

Answer (score 0):

I think `track by $index` should suffice and you will no longer receive that exception.

```
<option ng-repeat="prod in products | track by $index" value="{{prod.ProductTypeCode}}">{{prod.ProductType}}</option>
```

Comment: I need the `track by` to remain the same. Unfortunately.